# Jquery Fade in Text for Certain Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application I have a script that tells when somebody comes online or goes offline. I put the text of if somebody goes online/offline via `content = name+' went offline'` or vice versa. I then put that text in a div at the end of my function call: `$('#new').text(content);`

The problem comes with the fade out, all in all it's not really working. I've been trying to play around with it. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#new').text(content);
$('#new').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        setTimeout($('#new').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#new').css('display', 'none');   
        }));
    });
```

Comment: So you'll have many of these over the course of time, right? Many users coming online, offline. Boxes popping up, and fading away?

Comment: not really. It is for video streaming. If a user is streaming / comes on line the box should pop up and say a user has come online. So it's not going to be fading in and out constantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display:none` inside the callback is unnecessary, `fadeOut()` automatically sets the display to none after concluding.

```
$('#new').text(content);
$('#new').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    setTimeout("$('#new').fadeOut('slow');", 2000);
});
```

2000 is the number of miliseconds you'd like to delay it, change it to whatever value suits you better.

As @Pst commented, the function-object may be more consistent even though I personally have more issues with function-objects than code strings.

You may also use the function-object:

```
$('#new').text(content);
$('#new').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#new').fadeOut('slow'); }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Please use a function-object to setTimeout and *not a string*. It makes the code more consistent and avoids eval issues. In this case it would even allow using a variable to refer to `$('#new')`

Comment: Sorry, personally I usually have more problems with function-objects than strings inside the setTimeout().

Comment: @pst I edited my answer so OP may choose which solution to use, thanks for input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to provide duration for which the `setTimeout` should wait before acting.

```
$("#hello")
  .text(content)
  .fadeIn("slow", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#hello").fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  });
```

2000 indicates 2 seconds. If you would like it to stay visible longer, increase this.

Functional Demo: http://jsbin.com/aciwon/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this inside a `$(document).ready()`? If not, place it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#new')
        .text(content)
        .fadeIn('slow', function() { 
            setTimeout(function() { $('#new').fadeOut('slow'); }, 2000); 
        });
});
```

Also, be sure to initialize your element with a `display: none` and note I've removed part of the unecessary code.

Your `setTimeout()` code is wrong, you have to pass a function to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)?

```
$("#new").text(content).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
```